# show selected item on grouped_options_for_select rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For the purposes of an edit action I am trying to show the selected key in a grouped_options_for_select. The form is part of the model job delivery costs which belongs to delivery cost. Delivery cost has many job delivery costs.

```
= f.select :delivery_cost_id, grouped_options_for_select(@grouped_delivery_options), :selected_key => :delivery_cost_id,  class: 'form-control'
```

This is the method which creates the grouped_options_for_select.

```
@delivery_cost = DeliveryCost.all(:include => :job_delivery_costs)
@grouped_delivery_options = @delivery_cost.inject({}) do |options, delivery_cost|
  (options[delivery_cost.timing] ||= []) << [delivery_cost.title, delivery_cost.id]
  options
end
```

So to reiterate. When the page loads, I want the user to be able to see in the dropdown menu what he/she had previously selected.

## Update

I am using simple form. I am sure this is something to do with it, still need to research.

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same issue, did you find any solution?

Comment: yes, Badoo I did, I'll post answer